# Filter MySQL result set by result of inner select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have an MySQL statement that performs an inner `SELECT` and returns the result as a pseudo column. I’d like to use the result of this pseudo column in my `WHERE` clause. My current SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
    product.product_id,
    product.range_id,
    product.title,
    product.image,
    product.image_text,
    product.friendly_url,
    attribute.comfort_grade_id,
    category.category_id,
    category.category AS category_name,
    category.friendly_url AS category_friendly_url,
    (SELECT price_now FROM product_bedding_sizes AS size
        WHERE size.product_id = product.product_id
        ORDER BY size.price_now ASC LIMIT 1) AS price
FROM
    products AS product
LEFT JOIN
    categories AS category ON product.category_id = category.category_id
LEFT JOIN
    product_bedding_attributes AS attribute
         ON product.product_id = attribute.product_id
$where
$order
LIMIT
    ?,?
```

However, I get the following error message when running the query:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'price' in 'where clause'

How can I get around this and actually use the value of `price` in my `WHERE` clause?

Comment: you have an error in your where clause `$where` and u didnt share this variable.

Comment: Yes. Both the `$where` and `$order` variables are built outside the query, but `$where` will contain something like `WHERE price > 0 AND `price` <= 199`.

Comment: are you sure its `price`  column and not `price_now` because it saids unknown price column

Comment: `(SELECT price_now FROM … LIMIT 1) AS price` Yeah, I’m sure. As explained below, the `WHERE` clause is parsed before the sub-`SELECT`.

Comment: then try to use `price_now` instead or `price` , maybe its not allowed to use aliace there.

Comment: No. See this from one of the answers: “The `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause”. I did say in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause, so it doesn't say the alias name. You have to do the filter by the `WHERE` clause in an outer query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        product.product_id,
        product.range_id,
        product.title,
        product.image,
        product.image_text,
        product.friendly_url,
        attribute.comfort_grade_id,
        category.category_id,
        category.category AS category_name,
        category.friendly_url AS category_friendly_url,
        (SELECT price_now 
         FROM product_bedding_sizes AS size 
         WHERE size.product_id = product.product_id 
         ORDER BY size.price_now ASC 
         LIMIT 1) AS price
    FROM
     ...
) AS sub
WHERE price = ... <--- here it can see the price alias.
```

See this for more details:

- [**My SQL Query Order of Operations**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm).

---

**Or:** You can join that table, instead of a correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT
    product.product_id,
    product.range_id,
    product.title,
    product.image,
    product.image_text,
    product.friendly_url,
    attribute.comfort_grade_id,
    category.category_id,
    category.category AS category_name,
    category.friendly_url AS category_friendly_url,
    size.price_now 
FROM
    products AS product
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT product_id, MIN(price_now) AS price
   FROM product_bedding_sizes
   GROUP BY product_id
) AS size ON size.product_id = product.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    categories AS category ON product.category_id = category.category_id
LEFT JOIN
    product_bedding_attributes AS attribute ON product.product_id = attribute.product_id
$where price = ----;
```

Comment: he have the where clause `$where` its defined outside his query i think

Comment: You need `MIN(price_now)` and `GROUP BY product_id` in the derived table in the second solution to work as the first. And join it with a `LEFT JOIN`, not inner.

Comment: @echo_me - Yes, he had to compose the `WHERE` clause the same way but put it in the outer query no in the inner, the inner one doesn't see the `price` name in the `where` clause.

Comment: `MIN` is good, especially if you have `INDEX(product_id, price_now)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable:

```
@price:= (SELECT price_now 
          FROM product_bedding_sizes AS size 
          WHERE size.product_id = product.product_id 
          ORDER BY size.price_now ASC LIMIT 1) AS price;
```

Then reference it as

```
WHERE @price > 9000;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have

```
 WHERE price > 0 AND price` <= 199`
```

in your where clause

then try do this with HAVING clause

like that

```
 $HAVING
      //-- where $having  = HAVING price > 0 AND price <= 199
```